# How to draw a box over a contour ( C++,OpenCV)

Tags: c++, opencv, contour

I want to draw a box over a contour like this

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyAGY.jpg]

I find contour with this code

```
vector < vector<Point> > contours;
findContours(Iat, contours, CV_RETR_CCOMP, CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
```

And how to draw a box with `rectangle` instruction

I don't know how to use `vector < vector<Point> > contours` Can someone describe this

Thanks is advanced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the boundingRect method:

```
Rect boundingRect(InputArray points)

Parameters: points – Input 2D point set, stored in std::vector or Mat.
```

The function calculates and returns the minimal up-right bounding rectangle for the specified point set.

With this you will be able to use your desired method.